# Universal Image Loader enable/disable disc cache for each image

Tags: android, caching, universal-image-loader

In my android app, I am using Universal Image Loader to display images.

I specified in the option to caching images on Disc. But sometimes there are images that I do not want to cache on the disc. Is there a way to specify if it should cache on disc or not for each time I download an image and not only in the initialization?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created 2 options one with caching and one without and used each one accordingly.
Will leave it here in case.